# Align Items flex end react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am new to flexbox styling. I am facing problem while trying to align an element in the flexbox to the rightmost corner. I have written the following code to align the plus symbol in the image to the right corner of the red box but its not working as expected. Kindly help me to resolve this issue. 
[image: The plus icon in the image has to be aligned to the rightmost corner of the red box.]

```
    <View style={main_container}>
      <ScrollView>
          <TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={container}> 
                    <Image style={imageStyle} source={{uri: this.props.data.picture}} />
                    <Text style={textStyle}> {this.props.data.company} </Text>                  
                    <Text style={iconStyle}> 
                        <Icon name={'plus-circle'} size={20} color={'#003057'} />
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
      </ScrollView>
      <Footer />
     </View>

     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        main_container: {
           flex: 1,
           flexDirection: 'column',
           marginTop: 70
         },
         container: {
           flex: 1,
           flexDirection: 'row',
           alignItems: 'center',
           margin: 6,
           backgroundColor: 'red'
         },
         imageStyle: {
           width: 50,
           height: 50
         },
        textStyle: {
           fontSize: 10
        },
        iconStyle: {
           backgroundColor: 'yellow',
           alignSelf: 'flex-end'   //why is it aligning the image vertically ? 
        }
     });
```

Comment: `margin-left: auto` - this will push it to the right

Comment: Hey @pol,  react native doesn't have marginLeft: auto and I want to know what is wrong with alignSelf: 'flex-end'.

Comment: margin-left: "auto" works dont forget the ""

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`flex-end` work cross axis and push the icon vertically to the end (bottom of its parent), which you can see in your code, that it is not centered as the text and image.

To make this work you need `display: flex` on `container:`, set `flex: 1;` on `textStyle:` which will make it take all available space and push the `iconStyle:` to the far right.

If `margin-left: auto` would be available (on the `iconStyle:`), that would do it without the `flex: 1`, though you still need the `display: flex` on the `container:`

*and there should be `display: flex` on the `main_container:` too, unless that is automatically added elsewhere (same goes for `container:`)*

Sample snippet

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
span {
  padding: 5px;
}

div.nr1 span:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
}

div.nr2 span:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="nr1">
  <span>image</span>
  <span>text</span>
  <span>icon</span>
</div>

<div class="nr2">
  <span>image</span>
  <span>text</span>
  <span>icon</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this React Native or HTML? Or the concepts apply to both?

Comment: @HendyIrawan This sample show HTML and Flexbox, though the concept of  `alignSelf` is the same, and `flex: 1;` in sample _nr1_ work for both

Answer (score 12):

This will do it in react-native to have everything line up on the y-axis properly. The key is the `flex:1` on the center element.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}> 
  <Image source={{uri: this.props.data.picture}} />
  <Text style={{flex:1}}>{this.props.data.company}</Text>                  
  <Icon name={'plus-circle'} size={20} color={'#003057'} />
</View>
```